# VS Code Python: Wrong indentation for file

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

VS Code 1.22.1

Linux

Language: Python

I have a specific file within a project to which I recently copied text from the terminal to include it in a docstring.
By doing so I accidentally changed the indentation for that file to 2 spaces. All other files remain indented with 4 spaces.
But even if I change back to 4 spaces for that specific file, it changes back to 2 spaces the next time I start VS Code.
What am I missing and how can I fix this?

Comment: you likely have a mix of spaces and tabs in your code, change the settings so that tabs appear to be 4 spaces-wide. Alternatively, edit your code to use the same characters for indentation everywhere

Comment: I already used the function in VS code to "Convert indentation to spaces" and saved the file. But the next time I start VS code, everything is back to 2 spaces.

Comment: try enabling the option to show whitespaces, that should give you an idea of what's happening